# How to fix: Unable to start service Intent - RNPushNotificationRegistrationService

Tags: android, react-native

I am facing this issue for a couple of hours now and I don't know where to go next :)

I am trying to use the 'react-native-push-notification' library for my app, but android never call onRegister() (iOS works perfectly)

I created what was necessary for FCM, project, google-services.json, and settings. Firebase has recognized my app during the setup (so I guess I am good here)
I have tried to uninstall the library and reinstall it by following the documentation carefully (i think)
after a while, testing stuff, I am getting this error:

`W/ActivityManager: Unable to start service Intent { cmp=com.******/com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationRegistrationService (has extras) } U=0: not found`

in my react-native file

```
var PushNotification = require('react-native-push-notification');


                    PushNotification.configure({
                        onRegister: function (token) {
                            console.log('TOKEN:', token);

                        },

                        onNotification: function (notification) {
                            console.log('NOTIFICATION:', notification);
                            notification.finish(PushNotificationIOS.FetchResult.NoData);
                        },

                        senderID: "*******",
                        permissions: {
                            alert: true,
                            badge: true,
                            sound: true
                        },
                        popInitialNotification: true,
                        requestPermissions: true,
                    });
```

in `project/build.gradle`

```
ext {
    googlePlayServicesVersion = "+" // default: "+"
    firebaseVersion = "+" // default: "+"

    // Other settings
    compileSdkVersion = 28 // default: 23
    buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3" // default: "23.0.1"
    targetSdkVersion = 27 // default: 23
    supportLibVersion = "28.0.0" // default: 23.1.1
}
```

in my `app/build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    ...
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.+'
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:19.+"
    ...
}
```

So it seems that I have an issue somewhere that blocks the creation of the FCM service.
solving this should allow me to get the FCM token from onRegister()

Does anyone have an idea on how to solve this?
I would be very grateful :) 
thanks

Comment: I suggest using react-native-firebase. https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v5.x.x/getting-started . it's up to date and has straight forward config. also its work for android and ios perfectly

Comment: @Moein thanks, I will check their documentation and post an update a bit later :)

Comment: Any update on this? @Panda-Toine